# How to make a while loop last for exactly 1 second in ansi C?

Tags: c, time, while-loop

I tried something like this:

```
struct timeval time1,time2;
double time3,time4;
gettimeofday(&time1, NULL);
gettimeofday(&time2, NULL);
time3 = (time1.tv_sec + 1) * 1000000 + time1.tv_usec;
time4 = (time2.tv_sec)     * 1000000 + time2.tv_usec; 
while(time3 > time4){ 

    ...

    gettimeofday(&time2, NULL);
    time4 = (time2.tv_sec) * 1000000 + time2.tv_usec; 
}
```

But it doesnt work the way it should work.

Comment: any particular reason why you shouldn't use sleep? (http://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep)

Comment: "it doesnt work the way it should work" - which way does it work then? Does it last for less than 1 second? More than 1 second? Sometimes less and sometimes more?

Comment: beware overflow in `secs * 1000000`. Try `secs * 1000000.0` instead

Comment: Also [`gettimeofday()` is obsolete](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html). Consider using [`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html).

Comment: Can't use sleep because int this loop I'm waiting for a ICMP packet for a second

Comment: Then why don't you just wait for it instead of looping. All current operating systems provide ways to wait for network data for a specified timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem here is integer overflow. However, there's really no need to use doubles.

Use `timeval_subtract` as described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Elapsed-Time.html

and just see if the `tv_sec` component of the result is non-zero. If so, more than one second has elapsed.

Also, please don't call your variables `time1`, `time2`, `time3` and `time4`. It's deeply confusing for the poor person who has to read your code later. Suggest `starttime` and `currenttime` or similar.